# SOAP Request using Java

Tags: java, soap

I have been trying to send a request through soapui and I always keep getting the following error message:

```
 <soap:Body>
     <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Failed to process SOAP request. SOAP body not in UTF-16.</faultstring>
         <detail>
             <wsdl_ops:error>
                 Failed to process SOAP request. SOAP body not in UTF-16.
             </wsdl_ops:error>
         </detail>
     </soap:Fault>
 </soap:Body>
```

Has anyone run into the same issue before?

UPDATE:

I changed the encoding to UTF-16 and it worked for me. Now, when I send the request I get the following error instead:

REQUEST:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://www.broadsign.com/wsdl_ops">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:request not_modified_since="1970-01-01T00:00:00" token="0" requestid="1" version="4" name="category_mgr_list">
         <category domain_id="1719213" />
      </ns1:request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

RESPONSE:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl_ops="http://www.broadsign.com/wsdl_ops">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Invalid request.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <wsdl_ops:error>Invalid request.</wsdl_ops:error>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What am I missing? :(

Comment: Please post the service declaration (wsdl?). A note on stackoverflow usage: You should edit your question rather than put an answer as a question.

Comment: Did you find the reason for "Invalid request"? This broadsign is tricky one.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the service is expecting the request to be encoded as UTF-16. Validate your request and try setting the encoding in the request properties. Failing that, edit your question with the raw inputs and outputs.